# Losing colors when knitting a gt table to PDF

Tags: r, knitr, gt, html-pdf

When I run the following code manually, in my Rmd file, I end up with a (correct) colored table:

```
color_table <- c("darkgoldenrod2","darkslategray3", "darkseagreen3",  "lightpink2")
job <- c("job1", "job2", "job3","job4")

prof_table <- data.frame(job) %>%
  gt()

for (i in 1:length(color_table)) {
  prof_table <- tab_style(
       data=prof_table,
       style = list(
          cell_fill(color = color_table[i])),
          locations = cells_body(columns = 1, rows = i)
       )
}

prof_table
```

However when i knit it, the colors are gone. I am guessing that this might have to do with the knit going to PDF and the table being HTML. But I am not sure, and not aware of a fix. Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: While not really part of the question, it seems like `prof_table<-tab_options(data=prof_table,table.width = px(5))` also only works when manually running the code and not in the PDF

Comment: keep an eye on this issue [`cell_fill` no longer works with `gtsave` pdf output in gt 0.7.0 #1041](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1041)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation, as the [documentation](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_style.html) states that `tab_style()` will only work for HTML output. Here is the relevant excerpt:

> At present this function is focused on the application of styles for HTML output only (as such, other output formats will ignore all tab_style() calls).

Comment: I thought that this was not the case anymore (https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html). While it hasn't worked for me, I thought that gtsummary would help overcome this issue

Comment: While gtsummary might be able to do what i wanted, I only now realize that it always will turn your table into a summary stats table. Which is probably obvious from the title.